# A doubt from Theorem 5.17 in Kollar's Rational Curves book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Theorem 5.17 in Kollar's book, Rational curves on algebraic varieties, states the following. Let $X/S$ be a projective scheme (for simplicity, let us assume that both are of finite type over $\mathbb C$) and let $E$ be a coherent sheaf on $X$ which is flat over $S$. Fix a Hilbert polynomial $P(t)$ and let $Q(E/S)$ be the Quot scheme parametrizing quotients of $E$ with Hilbert polynomial $P$. There is a morphism $Q(E/S)\to S$ and the closed points of $Q(E/S)$ over a closed point $s\in S$ correspond to quotients $E_s\to F$ on $X_s$, such that $F$ has Hilbert polynomial $P$.

Let $s\in S$ be a closed point and consider a closed point in Q(E/S) which corresponds to a quotient $q=[0\to G\to E_s\to F\to 0]$. Theorem 5.17 says the following:

(5.17.1): Assume that $S$ is equidimensional at $s$. Then each irreducible component at $[q]$ has dimension at least

$${\rm dim}\ {\rm Hom}_{X_s}(G,F) - {\rm dim}\ {\rm Ext}^1_{X_s}(G,F) + {\rm dim}_sS.$$

(5.17.2): If equality holds then the morphism $Q(E/S)\to S$ is a local complete intersection morphism at $[q]$. In particular, the morphism is flat at $[q]$.

My doubt is about the second sentence in (5.17.2). Comparing with (2.10.4), which is the special case of Hilbert schemes, I wonder if we should have, the morphism is flat at the point $[q]$ if

$${\rm dim}_{[q]}(Q(E_s))={\rm dim}\ {\rm Hom}_{X_s}(G,F) - {\rm dim}\ {\rm Ext}^1_{X_s}(G,F)$$

Are there any other references for these results. Thanks in advance.